# Jquery datatable column header overlapping on table header

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have an issue in my datatable because my table looks like this

[image]

Anyone knows how can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
$(tbName).dataTable({
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollY": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "DataTables-s1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "aaSorting": [],
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false,
                "aTargets": [0]
            }
                ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i add your init code in my table the UI is fine. So there must be something wrong with your css.

Try adjusting the search input css like this:

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').css('margin-right','-10px');
```